# Solve the integral: $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-ax)dx$

Tags: integration

I am trying to solve the integral:  $\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp(-ax)dx$

Computing the indefinte integral gives: $-\frac{-1}{a}\exp(-ax)$

Now I was wondering if the following is correct:  for $\infty$: $-\frac{-1}{a}\exp(-a\cdot\infty)=0$

Am I allowed to do this in this integral?

Comment: You are just putting limits in the integral result. What are you basically asking ?

Comment: You are trying to evaluate the integral. And $\lim_{x\to\infty}-\exp(ax)/a=0$, yes#

Comment: You cannot substitute $\infty$. You have to compute the limit properly, as you probably learned in class

Comment: @FShrike i do not agree,  as the result depends on the sign of $a.$

Comment: @user376343 From context I assume $a>0$ because otherwise the question is meaningless

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \exp(-ax)dx$$
$$= \frac{-1}{a}\exp(-ax)\rvert_0^\infty$$
$$=\frac{-1}{a}(\exp(-\infty)-1)$$
$$=\frac{1}{a}$$

Comment: Wrong. It is not given that $a>0.$

Comment: I think it's safe to suppose $a > 0$. If $a \leq 0$ then the integral diverges. @user376343